# Навигация VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет,имеется вот такая страница,меня интересует как сделать так,чтобы при клике например на "повреждения" отображался другой лист,а навигация и кнопка назад оставались на месте? (хедер у меня есть на всех страницах всегда)
[image]

Comment: Вам стоит изучить документацию https://router.vuejs.org/ru/

Comment: Я ее знаю,навигация в хедере у меня работает,я не понимаю как менять только один лист вот этот,а все остальное оставлять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать вложенные маршруты, будет изменение именно части страницы, как Вам и необходимо.

Ссылка на документацию: https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/284588)

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

Подключите Vue Router.
Создаете компонент для листа.

На кнопку "повреждения" вешаете

```
<router-link to="/list">Повреждения</router-link>
```

В main.js

```
const routes = [
 {
  path: '/list',
  name: 'List',
  component: List
 }
]
```

UPD:
Также можете поиграться с вложенными маршрутами, ссылку сверху скидывали.